# Visual Studio 2010 C++ not displaying console output, despite console subsystem setting

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, cout

I've got a project that creates a console application, as part of a larger solution, however it won't display anything on the console. I've checked that `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE` is set for both debug and release, and tried both `std::cout` and `printf`, neither cause any output to be displayed.

The whole VS solution consists of a couple of static libraries containing the underlying business code, and three executable - the main `GUI (QT/OpenGL)`, the unit tests (boost), and this console app. Some of the library classes use `Qt` (mainly for signals/slots). Both the GUI and the Unit tests behave as expected (which, in the case of the tests, includes writing to console output ).

I've also tried adding a call to `AllocConsole` at the start of the main function - this causes a console window to appear, but there is still nothing being written - and yes, I have checked that the code is calling `cout`!

What else could be wrong? Is there another setting somewhere? or is `Qt` redirecting `stdout` without telling me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turned out that Visual Studio was over-riding the /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE setting with a /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS one in the Linker->Command Line->Additional Options page - deleting this made it work correctly...